# How do I get Excel to recognize different amounts for similar items?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to have Excel autopopulate insurance billing rates when I put in the billing code, with multiple insurances paying different rates.

For example

Insurance A pays Code 90791 at $104.
Insurance B pays Code 90791 at $98.64
Insurance C pays Code 90791 at $88.68

Insurance A pays Code 90837 at $93
Insurance B pays Code 90837 at $68
Insurance C pays Code 90837 at $80.84

How can I get Excel to read my client's insurance and automatically populate the appropriate pay code?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing sample data, but `INDEX/MATCH` or `SUMPRODUCT` can probably do what you want

Answer (score 3):

Place your data in cols **A** through **C**:

[image]

In **E1** place your desired insurance ID and in **F1** place the numeric code.

Then in **G1** enter:

```
=INDEX(C1:C100,SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100=E1)*(B1:B100=F1)*ROW(1:100)))
```

[image]

Similar to `VLOOKUP()`, but with multiple criteria.

**NOTE:**

This trick of using `SUMPRODUCT()` to get the row number will only work if a single row matches all criteria.

Answer (score 0):

- Create a table with the CPT code in column 1; and the Insurance Companies in the first row.
- Use `VLOOKUP` to determine the ROW, and `MATCH` to determine the column

---

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$F$1:$I$3,1+MATCH(B2,$G$1:$I$1,0),FALSE)
```

[image]